# How to send mouse coordinate using TCP socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I want to send mouse coordinate to android application using TCP socket.which is the simplest method to do this??should i send one by one or can i send both coordinate in single packet.

Comment: You can send a lot of data inside a 'packet'. I am assuming your packet is just a  stream of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can keep track of which value represents which coordinate any method should be fine. Note that the concept of a packet makes little sense in applications using TCP as the protocol allows fragmentation, but ensures all data will arrive and in proper order.

Comment: i am new to this...i want to send coordinate to other side..can u share some demo code to do this

Comment: The simplest example code can be found in [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html). Examples use strings, you may try using other methods in `PrintWriter` and `BufferedReader` classes to send and receive different types.